# How to use custom id field?

Tags: scala, slick

My custom id field:

```
case class UserId(value: String) extends MappedTo[String]

case class User(id: UserId)

class UserSchema(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {
  def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.Length(25))
  def * = (id) <>(User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

I cannot use the id field like this:

```
def find(id: UserId) = {
    DbTables.users.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption
  }
```

If id field is `String`, it works. It does not work with custom id field.

Comment: Have you tried `DbTables.users.filter(_.id.value === id)`? You need to reference the nested `value` inside of the `UserId` object.

Comment: Yes, I use nested case class. And your method does work although the auto complete does not show. Thanks.